# ListView databinding not populating list items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

im trying to bind a list-view with a generic list but it seems im doing something wrong.

this is my collection

```
public ObservableCollection<SharedFile> searchResults;
```

this is the SharedFile Class

```
    public class SharedFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public string Extention { get; set; }
    public IPAddress publicFileIpAdress { get; set; }
    public IPAddress privateFileIpAdress { get; set; }
    public string FileUserName { get; set; }
}
```

this is my xaml

```
        <ListView Name="lsbSearchBox" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=searchResults,ElementName=SearchPageRoot}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="340" Header="File Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileSize}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="User Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

after hitting the "search" button im filling the collection with data and at the end im setting the datacontext (but nothing happens)

```
lsbSearchBox.DataContext = this;
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.100).aspx):

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object.
>
> You cannot bind to public fields.

Make `searchResults` as public property.